# ASP.NET-Core TestServer doesnt accept Bearer Token IDX10803 IDX10804

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

My application is an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API.

I would like to test my `controllers` with the `TestServer`.
I have a `controller` class decorated with the `Authorize` attribute.

If Iam testing the controller without being decorated with the`Authorize` attribute, eveything works fine. Therefore my `TestServer` setup is correct.

Iam doing the following to set the `AuthenticationHeader` :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this.RequestToken(client).Result);
```

and request the Bearer-Token from my `TestServer`:

```
private async Task<string> RequestToken(HttpClient client)
  {
     var requestTokenUri = "secret";
     var tokenModel = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                         {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tokendata", "secret"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tokendata", "secret"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tokendata", "secret"),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("tokendata", "secret")
                         };

     var tokenPostData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenModel);
     var tokenRequestResult = await client.PostAsync(requestTokenUri, tokenPostData);

     tokenRequestResult.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     var body = JObject.Parse(tokenRequestResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
     var token = (string)body["access_token"];

     return token;
  }
```

This also works. If i print the Result of `RequestToken(HttpClient)` it gives me a valid `Bearer token` and the call `tokenRequestResult.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` also works.

Now, if I then decorate my controllers with `Authorize` and try to test my controllers like this (snipped) it fails:

```
  [TestMethod]
  public async Task ShouldDoSomething()
  {
     // Arrange
     var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Just some data");

     // Test
     var response = await this.client.PostAsync(this.requestUri, jsonContent);

     // Assert
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  }
```

remember: this works, if the controller is not decorated with the `Authorize` attribute.

But if Iam doing this with the `Bearer-token` and the `AuthenticationHeadervalue`, Iam getting the following error, as soon as its calling `await this.client.PostAsync(this.requestUri, jsonContent);`:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Error: Exception occurred while processing message.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Die Serververbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.d__8.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__24.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.d__1.MoveNext()
>   Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.InvalidOperationException" in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 2204.6107ms 200

I tried to set the `BackchannelHttpHandler` from the `JWTBearerOptions` to the one i get from the `TestServer`. But this is not possible since I need a `WebHostBuilder` object to create my `TestServer`:

```
protected HttpClient GetClient(IWebHostBuilder builder)
  {
     if (builder == null)
     {
        builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseContentRoot(GetDirPath())
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .UseEnvironment("Development")
           .ConfigureServices(services =>
              {
                 services.AddTransient<IAuthRepo, TestAuthRepo>();
                 services.AddTransient<IOtherRepo, TestOtherRepo>();
              });
     }
     var server = new TestServer(builder);
...
```

Now how should I set the `BackChannelHandler` inside the process of creating the `TestServer`, without having a `TestServer` yet?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Note: your question is essentially a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931629/hosting-asos-with-testserver).

Comment: Hello @Pinpoint the person who asked the question you linked only got the error IDX10803 not IDX10803 and IDX10804

Comment: + It didnt resolve my problem

Comment: The root cause is exactly the same: the JWT bearer middleware is trying to retrieve the OIDC discovery document using the default HTTP client, which can't work as the test pipeline is only in-memory.

Comment: The problem is i cant set the JWTBearerOptions BackchannelHttpHandler To the one I get from the TestServer because I need a complete IWebHostBuilder to create my testserver. I add this to my question its hard to explain but thank you very much

Comment: The recommended approach is to either disable the discovery by populating the configuration manually in the JWT bearer options (specially the signing credentials) or use a separate pipeline (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931629/hosting-asos-with-testserver#comment73045454_42935972)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do i populate the configuration manually? Any example?

Comment: Remove `Authority` and set the signing credentials used to verify the tokens signatures via `TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKeys`.

Comment: Do you want to Answer this? So i can mark it as correct? :)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure my few remarks qualify for a real answer so feel free to answer your own question ;)

Comment: Thank you anyway you saved my day!!!

Comment: Well is there any example for setting the IssuerSigningKeys?

Comment: @PinPoint and what's also weird is, if i just take out `Authority` iam getting a 401 `unauthorized`

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt Would you be able to add an example of setting the issuer signing keys?